# Getting Geometry error: One or more input features have invalid geometry from QGIS

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, invalid-data, agriculture

I am trying to use the "Split With Lines" tool to split a polygon layer that consists 1000+ separate objects.

[image: Split With Lines]

> Geometry error: One or more input features have invalid geometry.

The tool keeps finding invalid geometry.  I have used all of the general solutions like the "Buffer", "Fix Geometries", "V.Clean", and "Reproject Layer" tools.  None of them have worked.  Is there any other way to fix the invalid geometry?

I have manually gone through and fixed all of the invalid geometry.

[image: Invalid Geometry]

Then ran the "Split With Lines" and it will not complete.  It crashes out QGIS for some reason.

Why does the tool keep crashing and not completing the operation?

This is what I am trying to do for the entire data set:

[image]

Comment: Could you try use algorithm from saga or grass for spliting?